# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [OFDM transmitter bandwidth](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20132/ofdm-transmitter-bandwidth)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Shouldn't the Sampling Theorem imply that there should be no information loss at all after a signal is processed?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19868/shouldnt-the-sampling-theorem-imply-that-there-should-be-no-information-loss-at)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to intuitively understand the state space formulation of discrete time system?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/how-to-intuitively-understand-the-state-space-formulation-of-discrete-time-syste)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Real-time block processing setup on ARM](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20279/real-time-block-processing-setup-on-arm)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Measuring non-planar objects in image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/measuring-non-planar-objects-in-image)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Fit a line pattern on curve with unknown number of points](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/fit-a-line-pattern-on-curve-with-unknown-number-of-points)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is DCT basicly a filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20201/is-dct-basicly-a-filter)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Efficient Marker Detection for Images](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19876/efficient-marker-detection-for-images)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Avoiding identifying objects within previously identified objects in MATLAB](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20084/avoiding-identifying-objects-within-previously-identified-objects-in-matlab)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to select the center frequency and filter type for 5-band digital audio equalizer?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20167/how-to-select-the-center-frequency-and-filter-type-for-5-band-digital-audio-equa)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 7):

The big problem I have is the large number of questions which seem to have decent answers, but for which the questioner has not awarded a tick.

Comment: Precisely! I just wanted to ask question about that.

Comment: Related problem is the lack of upvotes on good *questions*.